# Issue an url when a button is clicked with it running as a background process

Tags: java, android, android-layout, httprequest

Recently, I am working on a quiz application on Android Studio. Let's say I am on working on a question and I have clicked on a button which will issue an URL (http://192.168.43.214/clicker/select?id=1&choice=a). The URL then will be captured into a database table as a response.

I had tried something like

```
findViewById(R.id.buttonA).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://192.168.43.214/clicker/select id=1&choice=a");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);

  }
});
```

This is near to my solution ( My database was able to capture the record ) but having a browser to open it is not intended. Instead, I want it to behave like a hidden, background process, just issuing an URL and do nothing more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Volley.

> Volley is an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps
>   easier and most importantly, faster.

Read,

- [Volley overview  |  Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/volley)
- [GitHub - google/volley](https://github.com/google/volley)

---

First add dependency to your `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
}
```

Then send the request

```
String url ="http://192.168.43.214/clicker/select?id=1&choice=a";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // handle response here
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // error
    }
});

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.
queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Off topic but what is the relationship between JSON and volley. Do I need just only of them to retrieve or push data into my Sql database? I am confused because my friend said if I was using JSON parsing, volley is really not needed.

Comment: There are always alternative solutions. For an example, you could use `AsyncTask` to send http requests, but I find Volley way more simple to use. There's no specific relationship between JSON and Volley.